# Moderate old chat messages

Tags: feature-request, support, chat, moderation

I (the room owner) was going to remove stars from an old chat message that no longer appeared in the sidebar. However, I can't find any moderation options either in the full list of starred messages or in the transcript. I couldn't load the chat back to that point either.

How can I moderate an old message? Is there some way to get the same moderation options in the transcript, instead of only in the real-time chat section?

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to? Starred messages are somewhat of a historical record, so I don't see an immediate reason to remove the stars.

Comment: It was an inappropriate message, and the poster wanted his stars deleted. I know I can flag, but I should be able to moderate messages as far back as I want.

Comment: I remember the rules were changed because people were abusing chat flagging by targeting old posts. Now you can no longer do anything to an old post other than flag for mod attention. I'm guessing that the room owner privilege of unpinning and unstarring went along with those. Well, room owners didn't really have much privileges to begin with, so I wouldn't consider it a loss...

Comment: @balpha Stars are occasionally used as a cheapo todo list. More commonly, stars are used to point to important information; if this information is obsolete, it makes sense to keep the message and remove the stars.